# Is it possible to do pull down to refresh and load more in customized uicollectioncell in uicollectionview?

Tags: ios

Im try the pull down to refresh in collection view but im use the (tableview pull down to refresh controller)same code for collection view. Please any one help my problem.

Comment: How is this related to Xcode? Seems like an API question, unrelated to the IDE being used.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: I use EGORefreshTableHeaderView framework file https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can write this code in your viewDidLoad :-

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];

    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshControlAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [collectionView addSubview:refreshControl];
}

 Now add a target

- (void) refreshControlAction
{
    // Enter your code for request you are creating here when you pull the collectionView. When the request is completed then the collectionView go to its original position.
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. how will you create the one empty row in collection when pull to refresh loading at a time.

Comment: Im ask create the empty row in tableview for show the loading view in bottom of tableview.